# Codeigniter: After cleaning my URLs(removing index.php) I couldn't redirect users who accessed my website to the new clean URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite

I struggled(because of the hosting company, godaddy) to remove `index.php?` from my website's URLs, after accomplishing that.
after that I noticed some users are accessing my website using the old URL(the one with `index.php?/`)
So, I tried to redirect the users coming from `index.php?` pages using **301** redirects, but  no-luck.
I searched the internet a little bit,
 but I think the reason behind the problem is that I need it to redirect from **all** URLs that
included `index.php?/` to `example.com` or to the same page request but without `index.php?/`(preferred).

for example: requesting `example.com/index.php?/site/category/etc` will lead to `example.com` or `example.com/site/category/etc`(preferred method).
And any other URL will be treated the same.

Here is my current`.htaccess` file (with nothing related to this issue) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**Update**:
Trying php solution:(credits to Robin Castlin)
I tried using hooks(based on an answer), but did not work!
i enabled `hooks` from config and `URL` helper is auto loaded.
this function is inside `application/hooks/MY_hooks.php`:

```
function redirectToNewURL(){

    if(preg_match('~/index.php?/~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {//check if the URL has index.php 
        header('Location: '.current_url(), true, 301); //redirect
        exit;
    }
}
```

This how I set up the hook:
from `application/config/hooks.php`
I put this simple array:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
    'class' => '',
    'function' => 'redirectToNewURL',
    'filename' => 'MY_hooks.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Eventually, I got no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$CI =& get_instance();

$CI->load->helper('url');

if (preg_match("~/index\.php\?/~", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    header('Location: '.current_url());
    exit;
}
```

Adding this to a hook or auto loaded helper should do it.

Comment: Aren't you needed to have a class? Or does that function get executed?

Comment: from codeigniter's manual: `class  The name of the class you wish to invoke. If you prefer to use a procedural function instead of a class, leave this item blank.`

Comment: Very well. Anyways, you can trouebleshoot this easily by `print_r($_SERVER);` and see which of the values holds your `index.php?/`

Comment: it's the `REQUEST_URI`, anyway the problem is related to preg_match function maybe the search pattern is wrong.